# Java: Saving state of Activity and its RecyclerView, before refresh its numbers

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have this disc golf app, which keeps count on players throws at a certain hole. Every hole has its own Par number. Every time user "go to next hole" (click arrow buttons) instead of actual intent to new Activity, this Activity refreshes new numbers to the same Activity (according which hole number is).

**At a default**, every time user changes hole, Player throw numbers (green background numbers) has to match to the Par: X, x number. At the moment my code does just that... but, when a user changes Player throw numbers (with plus and minus), it won't save those numbers that user set. I mean by that that, if user is at hole 1/18, and set for Player 1 throws 5 and Player 2 throws 4, and after that user goes to the hole 2/18 and again comes back to the hole 1/18, those numbers 5 and 4 at hole 1/18 are not saved, but instead it has those numbers that were earlier (default).

So now I need to save numbers according to the hole number, how is this possible, and is this even possible with the code I have right now, if not, how should I do it?

Assignment:

```
public class ActivityGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> parMap = new HashMap<>();
    int parNum = 0;
```

OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    updateDataSet();
    setLayoutData();
    setButtons();
    buildRecyclerView();
```

updateDataSet:

```
private void updateDataSet() {
    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);

    parNum = Integer
            .parseInt(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));
    if (parMap.containsKey(parNum)) {
        mGameItemList = parMap.get(parNum); // your Items list for the specific Par
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.size(); i++) {
            mGameItemList = new ArrayList<>();
            mGameItemList.add(
                    new GameItem(ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.get(i), mParNm.getText().toString(),
                            R.drawable.ic_minus, R.drawable.ic_plus, "TTL :", "0"));
            parMap.put(parNum, mGameItemList);
        }
    }
}
```

Build recyclerView:

```
private void buildRecyclerView() {
        mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gameRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new GameAdapter(mGameItemList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        /** Set buttons logic **/
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new GameAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            /** When player click minus button **/
            @Override
            public void onMinusClick(int position) {
                /** Take player par number **/
                String parNum = mGameItemList.get(position).getText2();
                int intParNm = Integer.valueOf(parNum);

                if (intParNm != 1) {
                    /** Change that number to new number **/
                    intParNm -= 1;

                    /** Set changed par number to the particular player (where button is clicked) **/
                    mGameItemList.get(position).changeText2(Integer.toString(intParNm));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            /** When player click plus button **/
            @Override
            public void onPlusClick(int position) {
                /** Take player par number **/
                String parNum = mGameItemList.get(position).getText2();
                int intParNm = Integer.valueOf(parNum);

                if (intParNm != 99) {
                    /** Change that number to new number **/
                    intParNm += 1;

                    /** Set changed par number to the particular player (where button is clicked) **/
                    mGameItemList.get(position).changeText2(Integer.toString(intParNm));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

logic of arrow buttons (change hole):

```
private void setButtons() {
        mBackArrow = findViewById(R.id.previous);
        mForwardArrow = findViewById(R.id.next);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
        mParNm.setText(intent.getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));

        /** Arrow Left Button **/
        mBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mHoleNm = findViewById(R.id.gameHoleNumber);

                if (holeCounter > 1) {
                    mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);

                    /** Set previous hole number **/
                    holeCounter--;

                    /** Set Hole number X/X **/
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

                    /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
                    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
                    mParNm.setText(intent.getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));

                    /** Display changes **/
                    updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

                    parNum--;
                }
            }
        });

        /** Arrow Right Button **/
        mForwardArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mHoleNm = findViewById(R.id.gameHoleNumber);

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                int holesNm = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

                if (holeCounter == holesNm - 1) {
                    mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_finish);

                    /** Set next hole number **/
                    holeCounter++;

                    /** Set Hole number X/X **/
                    mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

                    /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
                    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
                    mParNm.setText(intent.getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));

                    /** Display changes **/
                    updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

                    parNum++;
                } else if (holeCounter < holesNm) {
                    mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);

                    /** Set next hole number **/
                    holeCounter++;

                    /** Set Hole number X/X **/
                    mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

                    /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
                    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
                    mParNm.setText(intent.getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));

                    /** Display changes **/
                    updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

                    parNum++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `HashMap` to save your `GameItemList` where your key for the Map will be `Par`. Load the screen based on Par number. Also, your `mGameItemList` will be retrieved from parNum:

Global variable:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<GameItem>> parMap = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<GameItem> mGameItemList = new ArrayList<GameItem>();
int parNum = 0;
```

onCreate:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    updateDataSet();
    setLayoutData();
    setButtons();
    buildRecyclerView();

  }
```

updateDataSet

```
private void updateDataSet() {
    parNum = Integer
        .parseInt(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(holeCounter - 1));
    if (parMap.containsKey(parNum)) {
      mGameItemList = parMap.get(parNum); // your Items list for the specific Par
  } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.size(); i++) {
        mGameItemList = new ArrayList<GameItem>();
        mGameItemList.add(
            new GameItem(ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.get(i), mParNm.getText().toString(),
                R.drawable.ic_minus, R.drawable.ic_plus, "TTL :", "0"));
        parMap.put(parNum, mGameItemList);
      }
    }

  }
```

setButtons:

```
 private void setButtons() {
    mBackArrow = findViewById(R.id.previous);
    mForwardArrow = findViewById(R.id.next);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
    mParNm.setText(""+parNum);

    /** Arrow Left Button **/
    mBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        mHoleNm = findViewById(R.id.gameHoleNumber);

        if (holeCounter > 1) {
          mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);

          /** Set previous hole number **/
          holeCounter--;

          /** Set Hole number X/X **/
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

          /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
          mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
          updateDataSet();
          mParNm.setText(""+parNum);

          /** Display changes **/
          updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

          parNum--;
        }
      }
    });

    /** Arrow Right Button **/
    mForwardArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        mHoleNm = findViewById(R.id.gameHoleNumber);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int holesNm = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

        if (holeCounter == holesNm - 1) {
          mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_finish);

          /** Set next hole number **/
          holeCounter++;

          /** Set Hole number X/X **/
          mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

          /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
          mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
          updateDataSet();
          mParNm.setText(""+parNum);

          /** Display changes **/
          updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

          parNum++;
        } else if (holeCounter < holesNm) {
          mForwardArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);

          /** Set next hole number **/
          holeCounter++;

          /** Set Hole number X/X **/
          mHoleNm.setText(holeCounter + "/" + intent.getStringExtra("HOLESNM"));

          /** Set par number (Par: X) according to the hole number **/
          mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);
          updateDataSet();
          mParNm.setText(""+parNum);

          /** Display changes **/
          updateGameArrayList(Integer.parseInt(mParNm.getText().toString()));

          parNum++;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

buildRecyclerView:

```
 private void buildRecyclerView() {
    mParNm = findViewById(R.id.gameParNumber);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gameRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new GameAdapter(mGameList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: This remember changes that user does according to the hole number?

Comment: Yes! If it was saving it earlier for your old code.

Comment: Now I don't understand what u mean by that, "earlier for your old code". My current code does not save anything, it just forces same number to the players that Par number has, but if user makes changes, it won't save them (because every time it just forces players to take the par number)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes! it will save the state. try and let me know if any issue. Just use the parnum as key whenever you refresh your screen for different hole.

Comment: and this code suppose to take the place of my current method (updateGameArrayList())?

Comment: No. it will be in onCreate. If you are saving `mGameItemList` somewhere, save the `HashMap` data instead.

Comment: I couldn't make it work, can you check my code. updated my post

Comment: I put some more code, cause I'm not sure if there's something that messes up something

Comment: Sorry I have never used hashmap before so I'm not quite sure how it works

Comment: Hmm... in updateDataSet ---> mGameItemList.put(parNum, mGameItemList); "put" is read and it says "cannot resolve method"

Comment: also in buildRecyclerView() -> mAdapter = new GameAdapter(currentItem); current item had to replace with mGameList

Comment: Won't work... Now if I get for example 4 players to the game, it only insert last 1 selected, and first number is always 5, and those numbers won't save in any hole... I put also my plus and minus button logic if they help some how? they are in buildRecyclerView() method

Comment: I wonder that did you understood that for example here:

                        new GameItem(ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.get(i), **mParNm.getText().toString()**,
                                R.drawable.ic_minus, R.drawable.ic_plus, "TTL :", "0")); 

where I create new Item for recyclerview, that green background number, comes from the Par: number -> mParNm, I just wonder that is that correct to do in these circumstances?